# How to extract information from a pentagon shape? (picture included)

Tags: geometry, finance

I came accross this question in a practice test for finance. 
[image]

They asked us to find the value of the company's cash flow from operations in 2012 (blue line) which decreased by 2.3%. We have only the value of cash flow from operations in 2011 which according to this shape is 10 million. The answer guide indicates that it is 30 million and not 10. How is it 30 million? the blue dot on 2011 indicates it is 10 million.

Answer (score 1):

No, you just misread the graph, since the value of the blue line is on the third rung, it corresponds to 30 million.

Comment: The value at 2010 is 20 millions

Comment: Noted. I changed this as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

The center of the pentagon is at 0. The inner most pentagon is at 10 millions, the outer most one is at 40 millions. The blue dot on 2011 line is at 30 millions. Follow the pentagon to 2007, and you see a label of 30